# How can this PWM converter circuit be improved?

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, pwm, heat, mosfet-driver

[image: UPdated circuit]

This circuit is intended to use a 1-10Hz PWM signal as input and produce a 1-10kHz 10A PWM output. It will be used for controlling the speed of a water pump: [GP1352](https://www.whalepumps.com/marine/siteFiles/resources/docs/resource-library/181.01_v8_0417_db.pdf) The PCB will be ordered with (only) SMB components pre-assembled and will be potted once the SW has been commissioned. Thus keeping the heat low is important. I can only order the PCB with 1oz copper so heat from the traces is a concern as well. Therefore I am using 4 MOSFET's even though 1 should be able to power the pump alone. This way I plan to spread the heat generation out across the board to avoid hot spots. (The potting will be as thin as possible to allow the greatest heat transfer) The desire for low heat goes hand in hand with driving the pump to its full capacity as well.

I could explain the calculations and data sheet lookups I've used to arrive at this design, but the question would get very long and I think my intentions are clear from the description and the schematic. If anything was unclear I will elaborate in the comments.

So, how can I modify this circuit to better achieve my goal?

PS: This is my first electronic circuit design. Apologies in advance for the newbness, I'm doing my best.

Schematic updated 20191001 based on input from Brian Drummond and The Photon.

Comment: 3 questions : 1) Why are you using a high side switch? 2) Why choose NMOS devices for your high side switch? 3) How do the gate drivers generate the correct drive voltage for an NMOS high side switch with no bootstrap  connection?

Comment: On a lot of PICs the RA3 pin is input-only: this may be the case on your MCU, too. Be sure to check it.

Comment: @anrieff Thanks, you're right. I had the datasheet for the 220 instead of the 320 for some reason. On the 220 it was RA2

Comment: Another possible issue: depending on the type of motor in the pump, running it at reduced voltage might be bad for operating life. But I don't know anything about pumps and what kind of motors are used in them.

Comment: @Brian Drummond 1) 2) That was a mistake. I meant to make it a low side NMOS. Does that answer 3) also?

Comment: @K0ICHI it does. But now consider flyback diodes.

Comment: @The Photon It will not run at reduced voltage. The pump motor is designed for 12V. I checked with the vendor that it will also be fine at the 14.4V it will get from an ICE alternator. At 12V the data sheet says it pulls 2.9~3.6A depending on (normal) load

Comment: What's the point of the PWM if not to reduce the voltage seen by the pump? Why not just turn it on when you want it on, and off when you want it off?

Comment: @Brian Drummon I had some Schottky diodes on the output at an earlier design. But then I noticed the diodes internal in the MOSFET's. Wasn't sure if they should serve the same purpose somehow?

Comment: @The Photon The PWM is for speed control, but without the losses and heat that results from reducing the voltage in the circuit. PWM is the principle that is used in Variable Frequency Drives, which this circuit sort of is an example of.

Comment: Your pumps are DC motors. You can't do VFD with these.

Comment: And PWM reduces the power loss in the driver circuit. It doesn't reduce power losses in the driven device.

Comment: What do you mean by '1-10kHz' PWM? Are you intending to vary the frequency (why?), or have you just not decided what frequency to use?   Exactly why is 'keeping the heat low' important, and what temperature does it need to stay below at what maximum ambient temperature?

Comment: @Bruce Abbott The switching frequency will be adjusted during setup when I test it with the motor to see what works best. After I've found a good frequency, it will not change. I also would like the circuit to work with different motors, so in that case various frequencies would be used for different motors. The heat must be low because the PCB will be potted. The component with the lowest maximum operating temperature is the MCU, at 85 degrees C. The other components can handle 150 degrees C minimum. Thankfully the MCU has an internal temperature sensor, which I will use.

Comment: For the ambient temperature there are two possibilities. Either it will be 50 degrees C in air, or 0 degrees in water.

Answer (score 0):

One major problem: IRS44273L is a low-side gate driver IC, but you are trying to use it to drive high-side FETs. Your chip doesn't have any boost circuit to provide a gate drive above VCC like you need for an efficient high-side drive.

However, as other comments point out, there doesn't seem to be any reason you shouldn't control your pumps with a low-side switch instead of high-side.